# How can I "stop" or toggle this .mouseenter function?

Tags: jquery

My code is simple:

var draw = false;

If the mouse is clicked, it toggles 'draw' from false to true.

If 'draw' is true, it enables a mouseenter() event that colors the background of certain  (labeled 'pixels') when the mouse enters the div. This works fine, however when I click the mouse again and 'draw' is set to false, the mouseenter event does not turn off. I can set an 'else' statement that colors the background white again, but that's not idea, more of a bandaid...

This is all handled in one function.

```
var draw = false;
var drawStart = function(){
    draw=!draw;
    if (draw === true)
    {
         $('.pixel').mouseenter(function() {
               $(this).css('background-color', 'black');
         });
    }
    else
     {

          //don't do anything
     }

});
```

I also tried swapping the pixel class out to something else after it was painted, but I still run into a similar problem where the mouseenter event still triggers the class change whether draw is true or false.

I also tried a while loop instead of if/else, but this crashes the browser...

I wrote this on mobile, if there are any typos in the above code they likely aren't present in my actual code.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest thinking about this differently. First of all, create a CSS class which encapsulates your style.

```
.draw { background-color: black; }
```

Then, instead of adding and removing the event handler, always bind the event handler, and just have it do nothing if it's not needed.

```
var draw = false;
var drawStart = function(){
    draw = !draw;
};
$('.pixel').on('mouseenter', function () {
    if (draw) {
        $(this).addClass('draw');
    }
});
```

That makes it easier to see what's going on, and moves the styles out of your JavaScript into the CSS where it belongs.

Note that this code only adds the `draw` class and never removes it. If you want it to turn on/off on mouse enter, use `toggleClass` instead of `addClass`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to unbind (turn off) the event, try:

```
var draw = false;
var drawStart = function(){
    draw=!draw;
    if (draw === true)
    {
         $('.pixel').mouseenter(function() {
               $(this).css('background-color', 'black');
         });
    }
    else
     {
          // deprecated 
          // $('.pixel').unbind('mouseenter');
          $('.pixel').off('mouseenter');
     }

});
```

As stated in the comments, you should use off instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
    else
    {   
        $('.pixel').off('mouseenter');
    }
```

This does the trick. Thank you! I will keep the other solution in mind for future reference as well.